# Why is the element removed from the DOM?

Tags: javascript

When using .appendNode() it seems to remove the original from the page - e.g. the clickedEl next sibling inner node.

Why is this? Is this the expected behaviour?

```
var textNode = clickedEl.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0];
var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
if(video_text) htmlObject.appendChild(textNode);
```

Tested in FF 65.0.1

Comment: Yes, `appendChild` will remove the child to be appended from its previous position in the DOM, if any

Comment: If you want to duplicate a node, [`clone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) it.

Comment: what do you plan to do with `htmlObject` ?

Comment: htmlObject is to be append itself to the body element. Such strange behaviour. Thanks for your comments. Does any other methods remove elements from the DOM in this way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild, second sentence: _“If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position”_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are taking the `textNode` and appending it to `htmlObject`. This moves that node from its original location to the new location.

If you want to append a copy of the original node you can first [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) it:

```js
var textNode = clickedEl.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].cloneNode();
var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
if(video_text) htmlObject.appendChild(textNode);
```

Note that this will not copy event listeners to the cloned node.

Comment: Does this removing of the original happen with any other methods? seems odd when the is also a remove() method

Comment: It isn't removing the node. The node has been *moved*.